# Convert raw data to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have raw data in a string, which are basically multiple keywords in the form-

```
Law, of, three, stages
Alienation
Social, Facts
Theory, of, Social, System
```

How do I import it into a dataframe such that it counts repetition and returns me a count of each word?

Edit: I've converted it into the following format

```
 Law,of,three,stages,Alienation,Social,Facts,Theory,of,Social,System
```

I want to convert it into a dataframe because i want to eventually predict which word has the highest probability of reocurring.

Comment: You will have to read all the string steam based on a line by line.   Later onwards you would have to iterate through each element create a columnar based list and keep doing that. At the end you will have list of lists. then use pandas. By the way why do you want to use Dataframe? when you can just simply use file processing and dictionary as count space ?

Comment: If you want to count the occurrence of each word, you don't need a dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': [ 'Law','of','three','stages','Alienation','Social','Facts','Theory','of','Social','System']
})

df['name'] = df.name.str.split('[ ,]', expand=True)

print(df)

word_freq = pd.Series(np.concatenate([x.split() for x in df.name])).value_counts()
print(word_freq)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary

```
word_count_dict = {}
with open("Yourfile.txt") as file_stream:
     lines = file_stream.readlines()
     for line in lines:
         if "," in line:
            line = line.split(",")
         else:
            line = [line]
         for item in line:
             if item in word_count_dict.keys():
                   word_count_dict[item] += 1
             else:
                   word_count_dict[item] = 1
```

Since Now you will be having all the count list of words if you want the probability-based order. Its recommended dividing each value by total count of occurrences

```
total = sum(word_count_dict.itervalues(), 0.0)
probability_words = {k: v / total for k, v in word_count_dict.iteritems()}
```

Now the probability words have all the chance of occurrence of that specific word.

**Reverse Ordering based on Probabilities**

```
sorted_probability_words = sorted(probability_words, key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)
```

**Getting the first Element with highest chance**

```
print(sorted_probability_words[0]) # to access the word Key value
print(sorted_probability_words[0][0]) # to get the first word 
print(sorted_probability_words[0][1]) # to get the first word  probability
```